# Unable to reload Prometheus configuration

Tags: devops, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I've started Prometheus service with -

```
docker service create --replicas 1 --name my-prometheus \
    --mount type=bind,source=/tmp/prometheus.yml,destination=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
    --publish published=9090,target=9090,protocol=tcp \
    prom/prometheus
```

and can access Prometheus dashboard as per configuration made in `prometheus.yml` file. NOw I made some changes in `prometheus.yml` and want to reflect them hence hit command -

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9090/-/reload
```

but this command does not give any output and neither fails; it remains in stuck stage.

Please help to understand what is wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

Check the status page of Prometheus reload on `http://localhost:9090/status`. It should tell you whether the reload was successful or not.